# Android Lifecycles

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity, android-lifecycle

(Sorry for the wordy introduction.)

I have a 'bug' in my program where it randomly goes to an activity when it shouldn't. For example, let's say I have activities **A** (the *MainActivity*), **B**, and **C**. I moved from **A** to **B** and then **B** to **C**. However, while moving from **B** to **C**, I noticed that it goes from **B** to **A** and then A to **C** (which makes no sense to me; why does it not even 'come back' to **B**?). I wasn't able to find out why since I do not have any code that goes to **A** from **B**.

Here's the log:

> A onCreate (from: None)      // Just started the program
>
> A onStart
>
> A onResume
>
> Clicked a button from Activity A to move to B
>
> A onPause
>
> B onCreate (from: A)
>
> B onStart
>
> B onResume
>
> A onStop
>
> A onDestroy
>
> Clicked a button from Activity B to move to C
>
> B onPause
>
> A onCreate (from: B)       // Why?
>
> C onCreate (from: B)
>
> A onStart
>
> C onStart
>
> A onResume
>
> C onResume
>
> B onStop
>
> B onDestroy

Although I believe I'm not moving to two activities 'at the same time,' I thought I am since **A** gets called. In order to verify this and see what happens if I move to two different activities 'at the same time,' I made a simple program that moves to **B** and **C** from **A** like this:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, B.class));
startActivity(new Intent(this, C.class));
```

Once I press a button in **A**, these two get called. I have overridden `onCreate()`, `onStart()`, `onResume()`, `onPause()`, `onStop()`, `onRestart()`, and `onDestroy()` for each activity to put `print` statements to see when each of them is called. This was the result once I pressed the button in Activity **B** (to move to Acitivity **C**).

> A onCreate
>
> A onStart
>
> A onResume
>
> A onPause
>
> C onCreate
>
> C onStart
>
> C onResume
>
> A onStop

What I don't understand is why is **B** not being called (not even `onCreate()`). Is it because it executes the following command right after that there is no 'enough time' to even call `onCreate()` for **B**? I have been looking at [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack) and [this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity) (and SO sites) for a while, but I don't think I understand this behavior.

Is there a reason why **B** is not being called? Also, what could be a reason why it's moving to Activity **A** from **B** and then **B** to **C** (mentioned in the 'introduction')?

**EDIT**: To be clearer, I'm not trying to run two activities at the same time. It's the fact that (from the 'introduction') Activity **A** got called for no reason when I tried to move to Activity **C**. I was thinking this could be because of Activity **A** not being destroyed (still on the stack) though I'm not sure what the problem is.

**EDIT 2**: I tried to come up with a minimal reproducible example by creating a new program, but it seems like I'm not experiencing the behavior probably because I removed fetching data from DB (perhaps it's because of this?). I briefly explained what I'm doing in the comments below.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Switching between activities in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9937120/switching-between-activities-in-android)

Comment: You shouldn't start multiple activities at the same time. Activities are meant to be shown to users.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can someone please explain how startActivity(intent) and startActivityForResult(intent) are Asynchronous?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13919201/can-someone-please-explain-how-startactivityintent-and-startactivityforresult). It is being called, but you're scheduling two activities to get shown at the same time, so the latter would logically take precedence.

Comment: @Erfan Though the link doesn't directly answer my question, it does give me some insights. Thank you

Comment: @SonuSanjeev As I mentioned in the question, this was to see how it would behave when I call two activities 'at the same time.' This isn't what I'm trying to do. It was done to solve the 'bug' I have in my program.

Comment: @HenryTwist That seems to make sense though shouldn't Activity B be also scheduled (and Activity C is scheduled right after B, meaning B should be called at some point since it's on a stack)?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/a/9346671/12709358 , also look out https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/tasks-and-back-stack

Comment: @AjithkumarMuthukumaran Regarding the first link, I'm not trying to run a `Service` or `AsyncTask`. If you see my 'introduction,' you'll find out that it goes to Activity A for no reason (I don't even have code that moves from B to A and of course, I didn't press the back button). The second link is the one I have been looking at for a while as noted in my question.

Comment: @Droid I don't know anything about the internal workings of this, but it wouldn't make much sense for B to start as well. If another activity (C) is started before A has finished, then it would be logical to just show C. There would be no reason to maintain a 'stack' of activities if only one should be shown at a time.

Comment: If you're referring to the back stack, I would guess that B doesn't even get far enough to be added, but that's just speculation.

Comment: @HenryTwist After waiting for a while (15-20 minutes), it seems like B never got added (and yes, I was referring to the back stack; sorry if it was not clear). I believe you're right (though I'm still not sure as to why it's going to Activity A when I tried to move to C -- mentioned in the 'introduction').

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by that? The logs you've provided don't seem to indicate it goes back to A, unless you're referring to the `onStop` call?

Comment: I should have indicated clearly that the log was for testing to understand Android lifecycles. I'll add the log for my program that has a bug.

Comment: Now that is interesting... Can you give a [mre] so it can be tested?

Comment: @HenryTwist I tried to make a new program with minimal code but it seems like I'm not experiencing that behavior as I removed parts of code where I get fetch data from DB. Let me explain briefly what I'm doing and perhaps you can point out where I should take a closer look...? First of all, the **MainActivity** is basically a login page. I'm using PHP to fetch data from DB and check if the information is inputted correctly (by the user). Right after that, I fetch other data from DB related to that user twice; then, I move to Activity **A**.

Comment: + In both activities **B** and **C**, there is a `BottomNavigationView` which allows going from **B** to **C** and from **C** to **B**. As soon as I login in and move to Activity **B** via the `BottomNavigationView`, the **MainActivity** gets called (as it can be seen from the log). Other things I should mention are that in **C**, the user can move to the **MainActivity** via a menu (top right corner) by signing out, and I'm using StringRequest to fetch data. Also, there is no way to go back to the **MainActivity** (**A**) from **B** (unless you press the back button but I never did).

Answer (score 0):

After going through every line of code thrice, I found out that the problem was because I'm extending Activity **A** in Activity **C**. I don't have a very clear explanation for this but I would assume extending an activity 'creates' an 'instance'.

Comment: @HenryTwist I appreciate your help though.

Comment: Ah I see, glad you found the mistake! I can't see your code, but in your `C.onCreate` you will have called `super.onCreate`, which refers to `A.onCreate`. It's not that it `creates another instance, you're just calling the method directly.

Comment: That makes sense perfect sense! Thank you again.